# Efficient convex hull around rectangles (and checking if a point lies within the hull)

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

Is there an optimized way to get the convex hull, if I know my points are always arranged into two rectangles?

I programmed the classic convex hull algorithm (just by enumerating all points), but since I have a bunch of pairs of rectangles I was wandering if there might be a more efficient way to do it for this special case.

This is what I am talking about, to clarify:

[image: Convex hull around pairs of rectangles]

I tried sorting the points in various ways, but I just cannot find a general rule to optimize it. Is the basic convex hull algorithm the most efficient way to do this case also?

**Update**

To clarify my final goal, I have ~100 rectangles already grouped into pairs of two, and thousands of points for which I have to check whether they lie within each of these convex hulls, in real time. Now that I've given some thought to it, I guess the convex hull part won't be the bottleneck in the entire operation (but there is still ~100 of them, and I am aiming for realtime 60fps processing), so I might as well use a plain ol' algorithm as @BartKiers suggested and then get back to this after profiling.

I will leave the question open for a while, perhaps someone has an idea for an optimization which might be useful anyway.

Comment: There may be faster solutions, but I doubt you would need them: you're always performing the algorithm on 8 points, right? Manually sorting the points would result in pretty much the same runtime as a properly implemented convex hull algorithm.

Comment: @Bart: thanks, yes, always on 8 points, but there are ~50 pairs of such rectangles (100 rectangles grouped into pairs) and I need to check whether a certain point lies within each of these convex hulls - and I have thousands of these points to check in real time vs all of these hulls (I prune most of them by simple bounding boxes, but there is still plenty of them left to check).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I am right, you can enumerate all relevant configurations by noting that if the left side of a rectangle is more to the left than the left side of the other, then its two left vertices are on the convex hull.

With the same reasoning in the four cardinal directions, there are 16 distinct cases that you can hard-code.

### [image]

Another way to look at it is to observe that the convex hull is the tightest bounding box of the two rectangles, with 0, 2 or 4 corners "cut off". Finding the bounding box is trivial, and you decide if a corner is to be cut when it does not belong to any of the rectangles.

You easily derive a point inclusion test from this rule. If you already have a bounding box test, it suffices to add the corner tests.

Comment: Thanks! Although I am not sure how you got 16 cases? :)

Comment: If your goal is to check insideness of a point, you needn't even build the CH explicitly, just check that the point is on the good side of every edge (4, 6 or 8 of them).